Why am I getting higher sensor output when I have the tube I'm measuring filled with fluid?
I have a custom project to detect fluid color and turbidity (a reduction in light passing through) using an Arduino micro, a TCS3200 sensor, and an LED. The tube sits in a custom housing, and the LED shines from the other side and passes through it. (Details can be found here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/709495/how-would-i-decide-on-the-best-led-intensity-for-tcs3200-sensor)

Measurement setup can be seen here.

Tubes that are measured can be seen here.
I've found out that interestingly, the sensor output is increasing nearly tenfold when I'm measuring with a low intensity LED (68k Ohm, 5V, to obtain 100~ measurements of clear when I'm measuring distilled water). While it is somewhere near 4 times higher when the LED is bright (220 ohm resistor, 5V, as a standard resistor using in LEDs).
The light is also diffusing outside the tube when it's filled with water and on high intensity setting. Yet when its empty, it does not diffuse outside. (I'm guessing it's working in a principle similar to light diffusers people install to their roofs, extending inside in low income areas)

What is the principle behind this, and am I just recording noise when I'm measuring at high LED intensities (Because I'm intuiting that I am).
And here are the recordings over 5 minutes averaged 7 standardized fluids and the empty tube. Both for 66k ohms and 200 ohms.

Here is a very, very crude drawing explaining the setup.


Could you add a schematic (or drawing) of your setup? Right now it's hard to tell what's happening. Is the sensor submersed in water? Or are both the sensor and LED outside of the tube? What is the distance between LED, tube and sensor? I could think of two things. First is a lens effect because of the roundness of the tube. I think that's unlikely. Second thing I could think of is index matching. Whenever light goes through the interface of two materials with different indices of refraction, scatttering can occur. If the index of refraction of the tube is close to water, [...]

[...] you remove two interfaces as far as the light is concerned. In other words, for the light it looks like the rubber tubing and water are the same material. You could check this by comparing the indices of refraction of tubing and water. Also, you can see this by eye.

Basically, this is a PVC tube carrying drainage fluid from the brain to a collection chamber. Both Sensor and LED are outside the tube. Both Sensor and LED are <2mm to the tube. Adding a drawing (Though I'm a neurosurgeon and my technical drawing skills are... nonexistent...)

This is just a guess but I suspect the index of refraction explains the phenomenon. The index of air is about 1, for water it is about 1.33 and of PVC (I guessed that's what your tube is made out of) is about 1.521.
I made a crude simulation in phydemo ray optics simulator. First I created the scenario with air inside the tube. I used two circular arcs as the tubing, with index 1.52. On the right you see a detector which shows the power (P) in arbitrary units.

Then I added the water by adding a circle with index 1.33. The rays are more focused and more rays hit the detector.

The explanation is as follows. If the tube would be a filled cylinder with the same index of refraction throughout, it would act as a cylindrical lens. The situation with water is close to this. Here the light is focussed on the detector.
However, if the tube is empty, we have basically four surfaces that act as lenses. The two outer surfaces and two inner surfaces. The outer surfaces act as positive lenses: they focus the light. The inner surfaces act as hollow lenses: they defocus the light. Because they are close together, you can cancel them. In other words, when the tube is empty, it's as if there is no tube. The tube is not infinitely thin, so some bending of light still occurs. No focusing happens, which means there is less light on the detector compared to the focused case.
1 https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=organic&book=polyvinil_chloride&page=Zhang

Okay, thank you very much. I believe this does explain the phenomenon.

Although this does not explain why the TCS3200 is overstimulated when LED is bright, I suppose that's a question for electrical engineering.
